# Реализация выбора времени в форме html

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Каким образом можно реализовать подобный datepicker?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

гуглил datepicker - подходящий не нашелся.
пробовал реализовать через скрытые input'ы, в которые добавлялись бы значения из кастомного блока со span, где добавлялось/уменьшалось число, но не разобрался с .substr(), когда меньше 10. также не понимаю, как сделать ограничения с 0 до 24.
Вот пример по клику на увеличение:

```
$(document).on('click', '.up', function() {
    $value = $('.date-test .value').each(function() {
        $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 2));
    });
    $value.text(+$value.text() + 1);
    $value.append(':00')
});
```

Может быть есть какие то готовые решения? Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал с помощь slick слайдера и data атрибутов для скрытых input

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, более подробно как вы это реализовали, чтобы это было больше похоже на полноценный ответ.